# How can I configure a reverseproxy (at /) and a Laravel project (at /backoffice/) running in the same subdomain?

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, mod-proxy, laravel

I'm trying to configure on Apache a subdomain that should:

- Serve a PHP Laravel app if the request starts with /backoffice
- ReverseProxy to a node app otherwise.

I can configure the reverse proxy and the Laravel independently but not at the same time as the .htaccess on Laravel public folder conflicts with the reverse proxy configurations.

Here's the .htaccess on laravel folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And here's the relevant part of the configuration of the apache conf file:

```
        Alias /backoffice /mnt/volume_fra1_01/project/backoffice/public
        <Directory /mnt/volume_fra1_01/project/backoffice/public >
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>


        ProxyRequests On
        ProxyPass /backoffice !
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000
```

Even with the /backoffice exclusion every request gets to the reverse proxy.

By removing the .htaccess I can confirm that the exclusion is actually happening. So I suspect that modrewrite is messing with the URI in such a way that it gets caught by the ProxyPass rule.

This configurations seems like something that should be easy to accomplish. And it is very easy to do in NGINX. How can I do it in Apache?

Comment: I found a mod_proxy manual on the internet, in which I read "If the first argument ends with a trailing /, the second argument should also end with a trailing /, and vice versa. Otherwise, the resulting requests to the backend may miss some needed slashes and do not deliver the expected results."